# Changing the outline colour of BarLegend

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a `ListDensityPlot` with argument `PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic], Below]`. It produces an output like the following:

[image]

Can an argument be passed to `BarLegend` that changes its outline colour? In particular, I want it to be `Black`, rather than `Gray`.

Comment: try `Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, FrameStyle -> Black], Below]`?

Comment: @kglr many thanks - this works. I get an 'unknown option name' warning when I do this, though. Any idea why? If you want to write your comment as an answer I can mark this question answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the advice by @kglr, we use `PlotLegends -> Placed[{FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]}, Below]` since the default legend of `ListDensityPlot` is the barlegend.

```
ListDensityPlot[
 Table[x + Sin[3 x + y^2], {x, -3, 3, 0.1}, {y, -3, 3, 0.1}], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{f}, ColorData["BrownCyanTones"][f]], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]}, Below]]
```

[image]